# How to get XML file in camel

Tags: apache, apache-camel

I am writing a code where I am sending some employees information inside an XML file to some other location using Apache camel. Now , I need to change some values in the XML. How can I parse the XML and change the value and then send it to the location. I tried to do using .process() , but it's not working. Any suggestions will be helpful.

Comment: You need to parse the xml using an xml parser and then manipulate the message. You can do it in a bean or in a processor class.

Answer (score 0):

Use [Camel BeanIO](http://camel.apache.org/beanio.html) and parse your XML into Java Models and process them use the same Camel BeanIO schema to convert them back to XML from Java Models.

Answer (score 0):

Below you can see an example of modification of the XML document:

```
@Override
public void process(Exchange exchange) throws Exception {
                //Get your XML from exchange (maybe, your need to convert them to DOM Document before processing)
                Document doc = exchange.getIn().getBody(Document.class);
                //Here you can modify your XML

                //Modification example begin -------------
                        Element root = doc.getDocumentElement();
                        Element element = doc.createElement("newElement");
                        element.setTextContent("New element value");
                        root.appendChild(element);
                //Modification example end ---------------

                exchange.getIn().setBody(doc);                
}
```

I think, in your attempt, you just did not set a changed body to the exchange.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to work with Java POJO's and let a framework do the XML parsing / marshalling / unmarshalling, you can use the JAXB capability.

Then, you could use Java POJO's to do the "edits" (i.e change the values)  and convert to (or from) XML as / when appropriate using the marshal / unmarshal feature. This avoids the need for parsing the XML directly yourself (though that would work too of course).

More info [here.](http://camel.apache.org/jaxb.html)